# How can i do like the Pinterest unique modal process?

Tags: url, modal-dialog, pinterest

I have a question that

1. Point> I don't want to know generally function of modal, but like Pinterest
2. Question core > 1. **Can i change the URL when i use ajax without "reloading"**
3. Work flow >

   1) On Pinterest, i click on a image

   2) A modal window opens up, but the URL of the page also changes without "reloading"
    even though it use ajax

   - I've known that when i using a modal function, it dosen't change the URL on the page,
     but not on Pinterest
   - URL change e.x) rootURL -> otherURL

   3) I click the background of the modal, the URL of the page also changes without "reloading" 
    and modal windows closed

   - URL change e.x) otherURL -> rootURL

So, If you have some solution or information, please let me know that.
Also I have red related question answers, but it's not enough. and don't want to get information obout HTML5 API cause i'm not going to provide HTML5 service

- [How can I duplicate Pinterest website's modal effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252579/how-can-i-duplicate-pinterest-websites-modal-effect)
- [Pinterest like ajax loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882685/pinterest-like-ajax-loading)

Comment: Sorry you can't do it without html5. JavaScript alone cannot change the pre-fragment part of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Changing the Url without a HTML call
- Manage in the same url the Full HTML document and a JSON object (or a partial HTML response)

you can do like this http://mazzimo-in-london-eng.blogspot.com/2013/01/the-pinterest-url-sorcery-how-pinterest.html